# O que significa contar vantagem?

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês

O que significa contar vantagem?

Estava escrito numa poema "O faroleiro que contava vantagem". Mas não sei o que quer dizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pt-BR

"O homem sério que contava dinheiro parou. O faroleiro que contava vantagem parou. A namorada que contava as estrelas ..." ([**A Banda**](https://www.vagalume.com.br/chico-buarque/a-banda.html), de Chico Buarque de Holanda)

Vamos começar definindo [**"faroleiro"**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=faroleiro+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=faroleiro+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4694j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Literalmente, aquele que é encarregado de vigiar o farol. Daí passou a ser usado para designar aquele que é dado a **"fazer farol"** (criar simulações, fingimentos ou ações e ditos, cujo objetivo é impressionar e chamar a atenção para si)

**"Faroleiros"** são dados a fazer farol, contar vantagens.
(vangloriar-se, contar fatos, reais ou inventados, que servem para exaltar aquele que conta.)

> - [**contar vantagem**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/contar+vantagem/)  - se vangloriar, se gabar, se achar melhor.

exemplo: ele nunca aparece, e quando vem é para contar vantagem.

Comment: Obrigado a tudo!

Comment: Se a língua do usuário que perguntou for o inglês, uma tradução de *"contar vantagem"* seria *"to boast oneself"* ou *"to boast of his own deeds/qualities (mainly when exploiting the situation in his favor)"*.

Comment: To boast oneself não existe em inglês. Que pena que o "postador" não deu a referência. Essa música é uma das mais famosas no repertório brasileirode música popular de todos os tempos.

Comment: @Lambie Good call.